# How to send data that is not in a textbox via post in PHP

Tags: php, html

I want to send the id no. in a form so that i can delete the specific row, how do I do it?

```
...
$query = "SELECT id, text1, file FROM dynamic";
$resultObj = $connection->query($query);
...
<?php while($row = $resultObj->fetch_assoc()): ?>
<p><?=$row['text1']?><br> 
<?php echo "<img src=".$row['file']." height=200 width=300 />"?>
</p><form action="server.php" method="post"> <button type="submit" name="delete_data">Delete</button></form>
<br>    <br>
<?php endWhile; ?>
...
```

The button should then delete the specific entry only

Comment: AJAX, JQuery,... from JavaScript (client) to PHP. However, why not just use a hidden field?

Comment: `<input type='hidden' name='id' value='{$row['file']}'>` within the form

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone thanks

Comment: even better: `<button type='submit' name='delete_data[]' value='{$row['file']}'>Delete</button>` Button can have a value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place all into one form. Names can have brackets generating an array. Buttons can have a value.

```
<button type='submit' name='delete_data[]' value='{$row['file']}'>Delete</button>
```

Consider doing this with checkboxes and one button 'Delete checked items'.